# How to provide multiple languages for a Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently have a chrome extension that when clicked creates a popup with a form field that you fill out, pretty basic.

I want to also provide the extension in German but I can't figure out a good way to translate the HTML document for the popup into German.

I already made the web store title and description translated with the `_locales` folder and `en` and `de` sub folders with correct `messages.json` files. But I'm trying get the actual HTML document translated so when a German user uses the extension, the popup will automatically be in German and when a English user uses it, it will be in English.

It would help if you told me all the code I would have to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do it is via JavaScript :

`chrome.i18n.getMessage("name")`

The documentation for i18n : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298423/390330

Comment: `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage("name")`

Comment: @user2450043: Could you please share complete code(manifest etc)